# Git thinks branches are identical when they are NOT

Tags: git

One of my scripts had some errors in it, so I created a branch to fix it. The new branch is called 'fix_rotate_keys'.

I got the script working correctly in the 'fix_rotate_keys' branch. I created a pull request to merge it. But when I go to merge the branch with master, git tells me this:

> Branch "master" is already up-to-date with branch "fix_rotate_keys" in
>   repository "aws_scripts".

Really? Because when I switch back to master with `git checkout master`, the ugly error is there again when I run the script:

```
AWS user name: aws-test-new does not exist in AWS account: ./aws_iam_utils.sh: line 2266: [: : integer expression expected
./aws_iam_utils.sh: line 2266: [: : integer expression expected
```

What can I do to make git realize that, yes, the file IS changed and needs to be merged to master?

I am doing it from the gui and this is what I see:

[image: Git Merge Error]

Comment: did you push your branch from your local environment to the remote environment?

Comment: You say *the* GUI. *Which* GUI? There are many. Also, *pull request* is not something that Git does. Pull requests are a feature provided by GitHub and Bitbucket and similar hosting-providers, which attempt to "add value" to Git.  Pull requests are part of this value-add. Git itself doesn't do them; Git just does commits, with `git push` to send those commits somewhere, and `git fetch` to get commits from somewhere. (It may help to mention which hosting provider you're using.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to merge `master` into `fix_rotate_keys`.  Since you created `fix_rotate_keys` from `master`, that message makes sense (everything that's on `master` is also in `fix_rotate_keys`).

If you want to merge `fix_rotate_keys` into master, you need to do this:

```
git checkout master
git merge fix_rotate_keys
```

Comment: No, I am merging from fix_rotate_keys into master, not the other way around. I've updated the OP with a screenshot of what is happening. I am doing this in the gui.

Comment: What I have is merging from fix_rotate_keys into master.  "git merge branch" will merge from "branch" into current branch (which is master, because you checked it out)

Comment: When I try to merge on the command line with `git merge fix_rotate_keys` or `git merge origin fix_rotate_keys` the message I get back is `merge: fix_rotate_keys - not something we can merge`. I'm doing this from the master branch.  :/

Comment: @bluethundr Master is at an earlier point than `fix_rotate_keys` right?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, don't think so. I did a git pull in master to make sure I was up to date with the latest commit.

Comment: Have you pushed your local changes on `fix_rotate_keys` to the `aws_scripts` remote?

Comment: Did you fix the issue? It’s likely that fix_rotate_keys hasn’t been pushed so when creating a PR git says “no they’re the same”.